# Convert vector to a raster mask layer

Tags: python, geospatial, geopandas, shapefile, rasterio

I need to convert a shapefile into a mask raster layer using python. The new layer should have same extent, resolution and coordinate system as the mask layer; while the values should be either 0 or 1 depending on whether the shapefile is contained in the specific cell. How do I proceed?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.